# Nodejs async series - pass arguments to next callback

Tags: node.js

When you use async module, how can you then pass arguments from the previous callback to the next?

Here is an example from the docs on github

```
async.series({
    one: function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 1);
        }, 200);
    },
    two: function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 2);
        }, 100);
    }
},
function(err, results) {
    // results is now equal to: {one: 1, two: 2}
});
```

Comment: If you want to pass data to the next callback, you're probably looking for the `async.waterfall` method, and not `async.series`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can chain together asynchronous functions with the async module's `waterfall` function. This allows you to say, "first do x, then pass the results to function y, and pass the results of that to z." Copied from the [docs][1]:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback){
        // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback){
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
   // result now equals 'done'    
});
```

You don't strictly need the async module to accomplish this; this function is designed to make the code easier to read.  If you don't want to use the async module, you can always just use traditional callbacks.

Comment: Why the first parameter of  `callback` is always `null` ?

Comment: @Zen The first parameter is reserved for error callbacks if you want to add them.

Comment: if results are successfull then `callback(null, 'done');`. if you want to break the flow for special case then `callback("ERROR", error_text);`

Answer (score 16):

Another option is to use async.auto. With async auto you can specify the dependency data for a task and async will begin to run it when able to. There is a good example in the README.md, but here is roughly your series from above:

```
async.auto({
    one: function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 1);
        }, 200);
    }, 
    // If two does not depend on one, then you can remove the 'one' string
    //   from the array and they will run asynchronously (good for "parallel" IO tasks)
    two: ['one', function(callback, results){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 2);
        }, 100);
    }],
    // Final depends on both 'one' and 'two' being completed and their results
    final: ['one', 'two',function(err, results) {
    // results is now equal to: {one: 1, two: 2}
    }];
});
```

Comment: Hadn't seen `.auto()` before- amazing!

Comment: Working link to async.auto: http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#auto

Answer (score 9):

I spent quite a bit of time solving this issue because I encountered similar situation.  I tried both `async.series` and `async.waterfall`.

**`async.series`:** 
Used a variable to share across the callback functions. I am not sure whether this is the best way to do it. I must give credit to [Sebastian](http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice) for his wonderful article about `async`.

```
var async1 = require('async');

exports.asyncSeries1 = function (req, res, callback) {

    var sharedData = "Data from : ";
    async1.series([
            // First function
            function(callback) {
                sharedData = "First Callback";
                callback();
            },
            // Second function
            function(callback){
                console.log(sharedData);
                sharedData = "Second Callback";
                callback();
            }
        ],
        // Final callback 
        function(err) {
            console.log(sharedData);
            if (err) {
                callback();
            }
            callback();
        }
    );
};
```

**`async.waterfall`**: I tried using another callback function using `async.apply`. Here is the piece of code that helped me solve the problem.
`

```
var async2 = require('async')

exports.asyncWaterfall1 = function (arg1, arg2, cb) {
    async2.waterfall([
        // async.apply
        async2.apply(assignVariables, arg1, arg2),
        // First callback
        function(arg1, arg2, callback){
            console.log(arg1);
            console.log(arg2);
            arg1 = 5;
            arg2 = 6;
            callback(null, arg1, arg2);
        },
        // Second callback
        function(arg1, arg2, callback){
          // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
            console.log(arg1);
            console.log(arg2);
            arg1 = 7;
            arg2 = 8;
            callback(null, arg1, arg2);
        }
    ], 
    function (err, arg1, arg2) {
        console.log(arg1);
        console.log(arg2);  
    });
};

// Method to assign variables
function assignVariables(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    console.log(arg1);
    console.log(arg2);
    arg1 = 3;
    arg2 = 4;
    callback(null, arg1, arg2);
};
```

**PS**: [Credit](https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/14).

Comment: Both methods seems good. I have recently started using async. I just want to ask you that which is better or efficient method (for this case) async.series() or async.waterfall()