# Identifying callback data with async.js series

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

I'm using [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) to call 3 asynchronous functions that run database queries and return their data in the `results[]` parameter of the final function listed below:

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
      datasetA.fetch(sqlQueryA).then(function(data) {
        callback(null, data);
      });
    },
    function(callback) {
      datasetB.fetch(sqlQueryB).then(function(data) {
        callback(null, data);
      });
    },
    function(callback) {
      datasetC.fetch(sqlQueryC).then(function(data) {
        callback(null, data);
      });
    }
  ], function(error, results) {
       // Results is array of data containing
       // resultA, resultB, resultC.
  });
```

I understand results from all three asynchronous functions are in the `results[]` parameter. But what is the best way to identify the results from each query? I can think of three ways:

**1.** Ordinal - resultA will be at index 0, resultB at index 1, and resultC at index2. This is apparently implied in the async.js documentation, but not stated explicitly.

**2.** Modifying the callback parameter before calling async.js `callback(null, data)`:

```
    async.series([
    function(callback) {
      datasetA.fetch(sqlQuery).then(function(data) {
        data['query'] = 'A';
        callback(null, data);
      });
    },
    function(callback) {
      datasetB.fetch(sqlQuery).then(function(data) {
        data['query'] = 'B';
        callback(null, data);
      });
    },
    function(callback) {
      datasetC.fetch(sqlQuery).then(function(data) {
        data['query'] = 'C';
        callback(null, data);
      });
    }
   ], function(error, results) {
       for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
         // results[i].query will be A, B or C.
       }
    });
```

**3.** Inspect the data to determine which query ran.

I don't like 3 because it tightly couples the database schema with code (I only included it for completeness). But I'm less certain about whether 1 or 2 is better. Since the async.js documentation only **implies** order of results mirrors the order of the asynchronous functions in the array, I'm leaning towards option 2.

Above all else. Why am I even having this problem. Perhaps I'm using the async.js library incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **question** in the SO post [Nodejs async series - pass arguments to next callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424592/nodejs-async-series-pass-arguments-to-next-callback) provided the answer.

By providing `async.series()` with an **object** rather than an **array**, each asynchronous function becomes an object **property** and therefore has a **key**. The key can be used to identify the result.

Applied to my example, it looks like:

```
async.series({
    A: function(callback){
       datasetA.fetch(sqlQueryA).then(function(data) {
        callback(null, data);
      });
    },
    B: function(callback){
       datasetB.fetch(sqlQueryB).then(function(data) {
        callback(null, data);
      });
    },
    C: function(callback){
        datasetC.fetch(sqlQueryC).then(function(data) {
        callback(null, data);
      });
    }
  },
  function(err, results) {
  // results.A
  // results.B
  // results.C
  });
```