# Node.js - setTimeout function

Tags: node.js

Firstly, I am very new to node.js and I just started learning about callback function. So, I came to know that callback function basically works to handle multiple requests.

Then I thought of writing a function to see how it normally works without using callback function and I am getting an error here.

```
[Screenshot of the output][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/30AvR.png

Here, I thought it would work like : 
Every 5 seconds it would display 
Order placed : 1
Delivered food with order number: 1
.
...
....
....
Delivered food with order number: 6

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include your code and output directly in the question? Images can't be searched, copied as text, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expectation you should use async series method

Please refer below stackoverflow 
[Nodejs async series - pass arguments to next callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424592/nodejs-async-series-pass-arguments-to-next-callback)